# Why does `False is False is False` evaluate to `True`?

Tags: python, python-internals

Why in Python it is evaluated this way:

```
>>> False is False is False
True
```

but when tried with parenthesis is behaving as expected:

```
>>> (False is False) is False
False
```

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Chaining operators like `a is b is c` is equivalent to `a is b and b is c`.

So the first example is `False is False and False is False`, which evaluates to `True and True` which evaluates to `True`

Having parenthesis leads to the result of one evaluation being compared with the next variable (as you say you expect), so `(a is b) is c` compares the result of `a is b` with `c`.

Comment: Interestingly, you can chain arbitrarily many "is False"s and the result is still true `eval(" is ".join(["False" for i in range(n)]))`

Comment: Because it works for any chain - like `1 < 2 < 3 < 4` so:  `1<2 and 2<3 and 3<4`

Comment: IMO, this feature makes it read more like plain English. If you're explaining singletons to someone, for example, you can point out that `None is None is None`.

Answer (score 27):

Quoting [Python official documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in),

> Formally, if `a`, `b`, `c`, ..., `y`, `z` are expressions and `op1`, `op2`, ..., `opN` are comparison operators, then `a op1 b op2 c ... y opN z` is equivalent to `a op1 b and b op2 c and ... y opN z`, except that each expression is evaluated at most once.

So, `False is False is False` is evaluated as

```
(False is False) and (False is False)
```

The second `False is False` expression uses the second `False` in the original expression, which effectively translates to

```
True and True
```

That is why the first expression evalutes to be `True`.

But in the second expression, the evaluation sequence is as follows.

```
(False is False) is False
```

Which is actually

```
True is False
```

That is why the result is `False`.

Answer (score 15):

Your expression

```
False is False is False
```

is treated as

```
(False is False) and (False is False)
```

So you get

```
True and True
```

and that evaluates to `True`.

You can use this kind of chaining with other operators too.

```
1 < x < 10
```

Comment: So `0 > 2 is False` returns `False` -> what an intuitive behaviour :)

Comment: @pbaranski It makes more sense with parentheses: `(0 > 2) is False`

Answer (score 5):

I think that `False is False is False` means `(False is False) and (False is False)`, but `(False is False) is False` means :

```
>>> (False is False) is False
False
>>> a_true = (False is False)
>>> a_true
True
>>> a_true is False
False
```

So, you get the result.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> False is False is False
True
```

In this case, each of `False` pair is evaluated. The first two False is evaluated, if it's `True`, then the second and the third `False` is evaluated and return the result.

In this case, `False is False is False` is equivalent to `and` of results of  2 commands `False is False`